# How to find backup policy details attached to a VM in Azure using Azure python SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

How can I fetch the VM backup policy details for VM running in Azure cloud using Azure python SDK?

Also, Is there any way we can fetch VM start/stop schedule?

In Azure portal, I can see backup policy detail inside VM operations section.